# How would I convert a number (decimal number) to a string in Racket?

Tags: string, numbers, racket

In Dr. Racket, how would I convert a number (such as 0.8) to a string. Whenever I do this, I get the number in the string as a fractional form. I want it in the decimal form. I also want it to retain its digits to the hundredths place and I want the number to display "euro" after it.
Currently, this is my code:

```
(define (special-number pizza)
  (number->string pizza))
```

If I type in:

```
   (special-number 0.8)
```

I get the output as "4/5". My desired output is "0.80 euro". How would I do this?. Any hints or strategies will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `#lang racket`, then you can use the [`~r` procedure](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fformat..rkt%29._%7E7er%29%29) for this. If you are using `#lang racket/base` or one of the less feature-packed language packs, you may need to `(require racket/format)` first. `~r` converts a rational number to a string and lets you control the formatting:

```
(define (monetize n currency)
  (string-append (~r n #:precision '(= 2)) " " currency))
```

Here are some sample interactions in the REPL:

```
format.rkt> (monetize 0.8 "euro")
"0.80 euro"
format.rkt> (monetize 1.29 "euro")
"1.29 euro"
format.rkt> (monetize 1.234 "euro")
"1.23 euro"
format.rkt> (monetize 1.345 "euro")
"1.35 euro"
format.rkt> (monetize 1 "euro")
"1.00 euro"
```

Comment: The OP uses a student language. It's likely that their instructor won't allow students to require additional libraries.

Comment: Also note that by default, `(number->string 0.8)` does result in `"0.8"` already in regular Racket, because decimals are inexact. Unless you set [`read-decimal-as-inexact`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Reading.html?q=read-inexact#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._read-decimal-as-inexact%29%29), which is what student languages do.

Comment: @SoraweePorncharoenwase -- I don't see that OP mentioned a student language, or that an instructor is involved. `(number->string 0.8)` _does not_ return `"0.80"`, as OP desires.

Comment: Well, see the above comment for how I figure out this is a student language and not `#lang racket`.

Comment: Ah, OK, I missed the difference between "0.8" and "0.80". Anyway, the fact that the OP uses the student language still stands, and it would be nice to have a solution that only uses what comes in the language.

Comment: @SoraweePorncharoenwase -- that is not a constraint placed upon solutions by OP. Which student language, anyway? If OP comes back with more information, I may revise, but for now this answers the question as asked.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not helpful to you right now, but FYI, I filed a feature request for the functionality that you asked, and it's implemented: [`number->string-digits`](https://www.cs.utah.edu/plt/snapshots/current/doc/htdp-langs/beginner.html?q=number-%3Estring#%28def._htdp-beginner._%28%28lib._lang%2Fhtdp-beginner..rkt%29._number-%7E3estring-digits%29%29). (It's currently also buggy, but I also reported the problem)

To use this function, you can either download the snapshot release of Racket (https://snapshot.racket-lang.org/) or wait for the upcoming 7.9 version (scheduled to be released by next month). Both are probably not feasible for you.

Comment: Based on the [Racket documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/beginner.html?q=number-%3Estring-digits#%28def._htdp-beginner._%28%28lib._lang%2Fhtdp-beginner..rkt%29._number-~3estring-digits%29%29), it still looks like this does not do what OP wanted. E.g., `> (number->string-digits 0.9 2)` --> `"0.9"` from the docs, where OP wants `"0.90"`.